# Setting up a custom domain with Heroku and namecheap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I've followed all the instructions on https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains to get my custom domain set up, and it still isn't working.

On Heroku, I have the following domains:

`myapp.herokuapp.com`

`example.com`

`www.example.com`

And on Namecheap, I have the following settings:

**HOST NAME | IP ADDRESS/URL | RECORD TYPE**

@ `http://example.com` URL Redirect

www `myapp.herokuapp.com`. CNAME(Alias)

---

When I run: "host `www.example.com`" in my terminal, I expect to get "`www.example.com` is an alias for `myapp.herokuapp.com`". Instead, I get:

"`www.example.com` is an alias for `myapp.heroku.com`"

I can't figure out why it is pointing to `myapp.heroku.com`, because I have only specified `myapp.herokuapps.com`.

Does anybody know why this is happening?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

1) Go To Namecheap, and go to the domain you want to manage.

2) On the left sidebar, click "All Record Hosts", NOT any of the other jazz other tutorials tell you. No DNS pointing changes are necessary. It's easier to use alias.

[image: namecheap sidebar all host records]

3) Once you do, you'll see a line starting with "www" as a CNAME (Alias) option. Fill this in as your heroku app's domain name `example.herokuapp.com`

[image: namecheap CNAME alias location]

That's it for namecheap.

4) Then at heroku settings, under "domains", enter your purchased domain name you wish to be displayed.

[image: heroku settings domains]

That's it! 
It's as easy as letting heroku and namecheap know about both domain aliases.

Credits to this blog: 
http://blog.romansanchez.me/2013/06/08/point-namecheap-domain-to-heroku/

Update:

Apparently, heroku will only allow sites with `www.` prepended. To have a true root domain without `www.` will take some extra ninja hacking.

Comment: Also, don't forget to add in the @ the following: `@` `www.mydomain.com`, `redirect` so `www.mydomain.com` will redirected to `mydomain.com`

Comment: It's good that you point that out. For namecheap, they handle that for you, as the `@` character gets prepended to whatever you type in, as seen in step 3's image. For other hosts that don't do this for you, you need to add it in. it's good to understand what the most fundamental requirements are at the protocol level so you can adapt that knowledge anywhere. @ is what the protocol or program requires, and namecheap is simply doing some preprocessing for you for user-friendliness.

Comment: BTW, I tried to **CNAME** my `domain.com` with `myapp.herokuapp.com` but everyone said it is not allowed per heroku.com, So do you have any idea?

Comment: that's how I have it. my CNAME is the herokuapp domain name, and it's working fine. you tested it and it doesnt' work? you have all the other settings? Your heroku settings should have your actual purchased domain name as an alias, of course.

Comment: my settings like you, I've (`@` -> `http://www.shortly.pw/` as `URL Redirect`) and (`www` -> `short-url.herokuapp.com` as `CNAME (Alias)`), So when the user types `shortly.pw` it get redirected to `www.shortly.pw` but this is not what I want. I want that `shortly.pw` to be a `CNAME` to my heroku app *with no redirect*.

Comment: you mean `shortly.pw` rather than `www.shortly.pw`? I'd talk to namecheap chat support about that. The settings make it `www.` by default, so yeah.

Comment: I talked to them and they told me that `heroku` doesn't allow/support this. :(

Comment: is it terrible if you just have a www?

Comment: Blog link is dead.

Comment: that's why we have the answer in SO, and any links are supplemental

Answer (score 53):

**Update note:** *Heroku and Namecheap change their interfaces every so often. This answer may have outdated screenshots, but it will be updated over time. See these updates below.*

I've just done this myself so I thought I'd chime in as the answer doesn't illustrate how to get both `www.example.org` and `example.org` working. Heroku also changed its admin interface a bit.

### Namecheap

---

- First, **login to Namecheap**.
- Go to **Domain List** and click "Manage" for the domain you're configuring.

[image: Namecheap]

- **Set both record types to CNAME** (Alias) and enter your `<name>.herokuapp.com` in both url-boxes (@ and www).

(PS: If they're not there, click the "Add new record" and add them there.)

[image]

### Next, **head over to Heroku**

---

- Login and choose your project from the list. For this example, we're choosing the "Lakka" project.

[image]

- On the project page, click **Settings**

[image]

- Scroll down and find the **Add domain section**

[image]

- Enter your `example.org` and click Save.
- Click the button again, and input your `www.example.org` and click Save.

[image]

That's it, You're done! Now when you enter `example.org` or `www.example.org` in your browser, both will show your Heroku project.

In this example, http://lakka.herokuapp.com would be accessible (after DNSes update) also on http://lakkatracker.com and http://www.lakkatracker.com.

(If you want to redirect traffic from `www.example.org` to `example.org`, which is a good practise, you can use the record type "URL (Redirect)" for the www host name)

It can take some time before your DNSs recognize the changes. You can try using a proxy for testing, like [Anonymouse](http://anonymouse.org/anonwww.html), if your changes aren't reflected immediately.

Comment: If you don't see the option to "Add New Record," make sure your "Host Records" type is set to "BasicDNS" https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/782/10/how-do-i-set-my-domain-to-use-namecheaps-default-dns-servers

Comment: Shouldn't it be "URL redirect record" on @? I think namecheap says you shouldn't set CNAME record on both @ and www.

Comment: It should indeed. Using CNAME records on the bare domain can cause lots of trouble.

Comment: Thank you. That was helpful.

Comment: According to namecheap the problem with CNAME on the bare domain is that it can mess up MX records.  Thus if you're not using email on the domain I guess its ok? https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9646/2237/how-can-i-set-up-a-cname-record-for-my-domain

Comment: Very helpful answer! However, for what do I need the `myapp.herokudns.com` address (that is displayed after adding new domain on heroku) for?

Comment: @Ancinek: That's a way for users to initially access the application. Heroku provide their own domain (actually subdomain) for you to access your application at, should you not have a custom domain.

Answer (score 18):

Namecheap updated its interface. New screenshots to supplement other good answers:

[image: step 1]

[image: step 2]

[image: step 3]

Answer (score 5):

If you want all the traffic to point to `http://example.com` then do this:

[image]

and set both `example.com` and `www.example.com` in Heroku settings.

Then test everything by using http://anonymouse.org

Answer (score 3):

Set up a namecheap config that looks like this:

[image]

And a heroku config that looks like this:

[image]
And you're good to go!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your application, it may be a result of not using an SSL certificate. If you are trying to use an SNI SSL on the free dyno it is not going to work. In my case, I upgraded to hobby dyno and it immediately worked via the ACM.

Comment: That was it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 possibilities,

1. You had previously pointed the DNS records to myapp.heroku.com and the changes haven't propagated yet
2. This could be an artifact of the change Heroku made move apps from the heroku.com domain to the herokuapp.com domain, but I'm unsure of how this could happen or why it would happen for you; records for my apps all point directly to herokuapp.com, but I'm not using NameCheap.

You could try registering a different (free) domain with an entity like .tk to see if this is specific to NameCheap.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get both `www.example.com` and `example.com` to work, so one of the workarounds I found was to set the CNAME and @ to www., and then on the Domain tab, set "Redirect Doman" from `example.com` to `www.example.com`.

Answer (score 0):

I linked a namecheap domain to my Heroku app today and it is now a bit different, so here is what I did.

1. Add the domain (purchased on namecheap) to your Heroku app like `www.example.com`. The 'www' is important. Copy the generated `xxx.herokudns.com` link.
2. Now go to your domain settings on namecheap. Click on Advanced DNS.
3. Add the following two records:

- Type: CNAME Record, Host: www, Value: the copied URL from step 1.
- Type: URL Redirect Record, Host: @, Value: `http://www.example.com`

5. Save and maybe you have to wait for up to 30 minutes.